# Polar decomposition - expression of the isometry

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, isometry

Suppose $T \in \mathcal{L(V)}$ is invertible and has singular value decomposition given by
$$T(v)=s_1\langle v,e_1\rangle f_1+\cdots+s_n\langle v,e_n\rangle f_n$$
for every $v \in \mathcal{V}$, where $s_1, \dots, s_n$ are the singular values of $T$ and
$e_1, \dots, e_n$ and $f_1,\dots,fn$ are orthonormal bases of $\mathcal{V}$. I know that for every $v \in \mathcal{V}$
$$T^*(v)=s_1\langle v,f_1\rangle e_1+\cdots+s_n\langle v,f_n\rangle e_n \\
T^*T(v)=s_1^2\langle v,e_1\rangle e_1+\cdots+s_n^2\langle v,e_n\rangle e_n; \\
\sqrt{T^*T}(v)=s_1\langle v,e_1\rangle e_1+\cdots+s_n\langle v,e_n\rangle e_n; \\
T^{-1}(v)=\frac{\langle v,f_1\rangle}{s_1} e_1+\cdots+\frac{\langle v,f_n\rangle}{s_n} e_n.$$
I also know, from the polar decomposition, that there is a isometry $S \in \mathcal{L(V)}$ such that $T=S \sqrt{T^∗T}$. Based on the expressions above, how can I deduce a mathematical expression for $S$?

Comment: You can solve the equation $T = S\sqrt{T^*T}$ to get $S = T(T^*T)^{-1/2}$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all,  solve the equation $T = S\sqrt{T^*T}$ to get $S = T(T^*T)^{-1/2}$. Verify that the inverse of $\sqrt{T^*T}$ is given by
$$
(T^*T)^{-1/2}(v) = \sum_i s_i^{-1} \langle v,e_i\rangle e_i.
$$
Next, compute the composition
$$
\begin{align}
T(T^*T)^{-1/2}(v) &= T \sum_i s_i^{-1} \langle v,e_i\rangle e_i
\\ & = \sum_j s_j \left \langle \sum_i s_i^{-1} \langle v,e_i\rangle e_i,e_j \right \rangle f_j
\\ & = \sum_{i,j} s_i^{-1}s_j \langle v,e_i \rangle \langle e_i,e_j \rangle f_j
\\ & = \sum_{i} s_i^{-1}s_i \langle v,e_i \rangle  f_i = 
\sum_{i} \langle v,e_i \rangle  f_i.
\end{align}
$$